# How to display day names and number from current date in android

Tags: java, android, calendar, dayofweek, dayofmonth

Hi I am implementing a feature called calendar. Now From current month name and current year from this how to display day names and day number .

Code:

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
            Date startDate = cal.getTime();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
            Date endDate = cal.getTime();

            Log.d(TAG, "Start Date = " + startDate);
            Log.d(TAG, "End Date = " + endDate);
```

Example: `Dec 2020`

Expected output :

```
Wed -9
Thu -10
Fri -11
Sat- 12
Sun- 13
```

Can any one help me How to achieve my goal

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a [`for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) declared with

1. **Initial value** as today
2. **Terminating value** as the end of the month
3. **Increment value** of one day

and inside the body of the loop, print the 3-letter weekday name (i.e. `EEE`) and the day-of-month (i.e. `d`) of the date formatted with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE - d", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE - d", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        for (LocalDate date = today; !date.isAfter(today.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())); date = date
                .plusDays(1)) {
            System.out.println(date.format(formatter));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Fri - 11
Sat - 12
Sun - 13
...
...
...
Wed - 30
Thu - 31
```

**Note:** all the dates of this month, starting from today, are of two digits and therefore it doesn't matter whether you use `d` or `dd` for day-of-month. However, if your requirement is to print the day-of-month always in two digits (e.g. `01` instead of `1`), use `dd` in the `DateTimeFormatter` pattern.

---

**Some useful notes:**

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: suppose if today is tue how to change that text to today

Comment: @jyothisri - It's not difficult to convert a day (e.g. `Tue`) into a `LocalDate` if you know the week number e.g. `Tue` comes every week and if you provide me with the week number (of the month e.g. 2nd `Tue` of the current month or something like `Tue` of week 49 of the year), I will let you know how to convert `Tue` of that week into a `LocalDate`. Is this what you are looking for something else?

Comment: I Want to display instead of todays name as tue then want to display the Today

Comment: @jyothisri - For this, use `System.out.println(date.equals(today) ? "Today - " + date.getDayOfMonth() : date.format(formatter));`. Feel free to comment in case of any further query.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and calendar work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE - ppd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    LocalDate currentDay = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).atDay(1);
    LocalDate firstInNextMonth = currentDay.plusMonths(1);
    while (currentDay.isBefore(firstInNextMonth)) {
        System.out.println(currentDay.format(dayFormatter));
        currentDay = currentDay.plusDays(1);
    }
```

Output when run in December 2020 (excerpt):

```
Tue -  1
Wed -  2
Thu -  3
Fri -  4
Sat -  5
Sun -  6
Mon -  7
Tue -  8
Wed -  9
Thu - 10
Fri - 11
(--- cut ---)
Tue - 29
Wed - 30
Thu - 31
```

For the right-aligned day of the month in the print-out, I have used `ppd` in the format pattern string. For display in a phone app, you may prefer just `d`.

Edit: **For the days of the coming week** initialize the dates like this:

```
    LocalDate currentDay = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDate endDateExclusive = currentDay.plusWeeks(1);
```

When running the code in the last week of the month you may have days of the following month included, which doesn’t seem to agree with what you said: *Now From current month name and current year …*. I hope you’ll find a satisfactory solution.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with sub-packages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I am getting output like this wed 2, thu 3,fri 4,fri 5, sat 6 .But I am expecting from cureent week dates Thu 10,Fri 11,Sat 12, sun 13 this is what I am Expecting

Comment: No Expected Output I was mentioned the same

Comment: is after dates want to display

Comment: I edited and show another way to initialize the start and end date. Maybe you can use it as inspiration to find a way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the work.

```
public void printDaysOfMonth(int year, int month) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE-d", Locale.ENGLISH);
    calendar.set(year, month, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
        String fEndDate = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(fEndDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

}
```

**Note:**  January-`0`  and  December - `11`

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).